# Python3 Datetime (delta) to Seconds (Including Days)

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Hopefully just a simple question. I want to convert a datetime object to seconds and *include* the days. I've just noticed that my code skipped the day. Please note times are just an example and not 100% accurate.

Content of oldtime.txt (2 days ago):

```
2021-09-16 19:34:33.569827
```

Code:

```
oldtimefile = open('oldtime.txt', 'r+')
oldtme = oldtimefile.read()
datetimeobj = datetime.strptime(oldtme, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
finaltime = datetime.now() - datetimeobj
print(finaltime.seconds)
```

If I just print `finaltime` then I get `1 day, 22:13:30.231916`.

Now if we take today's date and time - just for argument sake - (`2021-09-18 17:34:33.569827`) as `now` then I actually get `80010` seconds instead of roughly `172800` seconds. It's ignoring the day part.

How can I include the day and convert the entire object to seconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.seconds` you can use [`.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```py
from datetime import datetime

oldtme = "2021-09-16 19:34:33.569827"
datetimeobj = datetime.strptime(oldtme, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
finaltime = datetime.now() - datetimeobj
print(finaltime.total_seconds())
```

Prints:

```
164254.768354
```